# Python Inheritance from immutable class int, why arguments' order matters when copying?

Tags: python, inheritance, int, copy, immutability

I am trying to implement a class inherited from int, and adding some members to it, but I find the instance from the derived class cannot be copied correctly(even deep copy) if the order of arguments change, see the example below, trying create a positive int class:

```
# Example 1
import copy as cp
class PositiveInt(int): 
def __new__(cls, arg = 1, arg0 = 2, arg1 = 3):
    if arg < 0:
        arg = -arg
    return super(PositiveInt, cls).__new__(cls, arg)
def __init__(self, arg = 1, arg0 = 2, arg1 = 3):
    self.arg0 = arg0
    self.arg1 = arg1

n = PositiveInt(3, 4, 5)
m = cp.copy(n)
print(n, n.arg0, n.arg1)
print(m, m.arg0, m.arg1)
```

This will print:
(3, 4, 5)
(3, 4, 5)

```
# Example 2
class PositiveInt(int):
def __new__(cls, arg0 = 2, arg = 1, arg1 = 3):
    if arg < 0:
        arg = -arg
    return super(PositiveInt, cls).__new__(cls, arg)
def __init__(self, arg0 = 2, arg = 1, arg1 = 3):
    self.arg0 = arg0
    self.arg1 = arg1

n = PositiveInt(4, 3, 5)
m = cp.copy(n)
print(n, n.arg0, n.arg1)
print(m, m.arg0, m.arg1)
```

This will print:
(3, 4, 5)
(1, 4, 5)

The only difference is the order of arguments. It seems in example 2, copy will use the default value of arg for instantiation in **new**, but this is not the case in example 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`m = cp.copy(n)` ends up calling  `m = PositiveInt(n)` which in turn is calling `m=PositiveInt(3)`

you could subclass `__copy__`

```
def __copy__(self):
    return PositiveInt(self.arg0,self,self.arg1)
```

or you could check the first argument in `__new__` (maybe... I actually dont think this will work)... but really you should just subclass `__copy__`